# wifi.log: what's going on?

Tags: network, macos, wifi, logs

When I look at my wifi.log, I get the following output:

[image]

Note that it's adding a few lines every few seconds. What's going on? Should I be concerned that it seems to be "changing quality" every few seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.What are "**Scan requests**":
The scan requests are the system (the airportd dameon) scanning for available WiFi networks.
The precedure maybe runs like this:

1. Application send a request to airportd
2. ScanManager receive broadcast scan request from airportd
3. ScanManager initialize scan
4. ScanManager return scan results to airportd

("scan cache updated" will show due to a fresh scan result)

---

2.Possible Cause:
[image: Google Chrome trigger the scan]

Shown in the picture,**Google Chrome** may trigger the scan frequently.Close chrome and QUIT chrome should stop this "annoying" loop.

---

3.Link quality:
Since it doesn't change a lot in the log,**No need to worry** about if your battery life does not seem to be suffering

Comment: Does chrome have a setting or config flag to disable these requests? they interfere with video conferencing.